# onLowMemory() not called when app kill due to memory low

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have put onLowMemory() in both Activity and Application classes, notice that when the app is killed due to low memory, both method is not triggered.

Is there callback method to find out the cause the app killed ? Especially, not the normal flow that will trigger onPause(), onDestroy(). 
E.g. memory low / force stop.

Thanks

My app is killed because I try to run multiple of other apps to simulate the low memory scenario. I have a broadcast receiver watch if the app is killed.  I find that if the app is killed by low memory by OS is tend to restart the app. If the app is force to quit, like removing it using the app snapshot (hold home btn). It will not restart.  My receiver will always ask whether the user would like to restart the app. The problem is the app already restarted if it is cause by low memory. My broadcast receiver unable to tell how the app end and display accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When onLowMemory() is called is not precisely defined but generally happens when the Android run-time has already killed everything it safely can. In other words, when the only things left in memory are active services and the visible UI. Only at that point will Android likely call this method on every running process in an attempt to ask those remaining processes to trim their memory usage. It is not called as a warning that your app is low on memory in its own particular address space.

If your app uses a lot of memory and is not currently visible, it will always be a likely candidate for being killed. As for finding out the cause of your app being killed, the reason is always going to be that the Android run-time simply needed its memory address space back. There is no callback made to your app beyond the usual onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy() sequence. Force Stops only occur when your app crashes or becomes unresponsive.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. My app is killed because I try to run multiple of other apps to simulate the low memory scenario. I have a broadcast receiver watch if the app is killed.  I find that if the app is killed by low memory by OS is tend to restart the app. If the app is force to quit, like removing it using the app snapshot. It will not restart.  My broadcast receive will ask whether the user would like to restart the app. The problem is the app already restarted if it is cause by low memory. My broadcast receiver unable to tell how the app end and display accordingly

Comment: Yes, when the run-time needs to kill your app for resources, it will potentially restart it again when it can (although that's not a given). As opposed to closing it manually from the app snapshot list which is clearly a user request for it to be gone and stay gone. I'm interested as to why you want to keep your app alive? Is it because you want it to remain in the app snapshot list?

Comment: I want to keep the app alive as it is connected to a health related device via bluetooth, the data receive is important and have to keep the app running. is there a way to configure the app that it does not restart once it is killed due to low memory?

Comment: I think your best approach is to investigate using a Service along with your app. They have a higher priority than inactive or stopped activities making them far less likely to be terminated by the run-time and you can configure them to auto-restart when resoures become available. So your Service would manage the data feed (e.g. logging it to a file) and your Activity is just the front end to view that data (so it wouldn't need to stay alive). We're getting beyond the scope of this specific question now so I'll finish by saying good luck with your app - it sounds like a worthwhile project.